# Find linear part and slope in curve

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

For a device that monitors the mass change in function of time, we would like to calculate the slope of the linear part of the data.

The example shown below is produced by reading a dataframe produced by the device.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Find DataFrame
df = pd.read_table("raw_data.csv", sep =";", skiprows = 11, decimal = ",")

# Plot figures
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df["Time(s)"], df["Mass(g)"], label = "Raw Data")
plt.axvspan(2, 17, color="b", alpha=0.2)
plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
plt.ylabel("Mass (g)")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.axis([0, None, 0, None])
plt.show()
```

[image: Example curve]

Is it possible to fit the linear part in this curve (roughly the highlighted part) and calculate the slope of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **numpy.polyfit()** :

```
df_sampled = df[:max_value] #select the points you want to keep
m, p = numpy.polyfit(df_sampled.index, df_sampled, deg=1)
```

The function returns the **slope** and the **intercept** of your linear regression.

Comment: Thanks, this already helps! But selecting the points in the linear part manually can only be used for 1 file at a time, as I have more than 300 I was looking for a more generic way to find this linear part?

Comment: If all your curves look like that, what you can do is set a threshold to 95% or 90% of your maximum value mass and take its abscissa as the end of your linear part. I don't know what you are trying to model, but generally this is what we do when we want to separate the transitory and permanent states in physics.